# Best Practices for Storing PDF files

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-files

I am working on a ASP.NET  project with SQL as back end.(This SQL server is provisioned in cloud using Azure) Part  of my Project, I need to store lot of PDF file (like invoices, Customer Updates) etc. The Number of these PDF files are expected to big in number (5TB may be)
Now that I provisioned my SQL server in Azure, I am looking best practices On Where I can store the files?  Can I use Azure Blob? Is it cheaper? or storing in SQL server itself is better (I know backup is a concern)
Or any other suggestion?

Comment: similar questions asked many times

Answer (score 1):

Using [Azure Blob Storage](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/storage/blobs/) is way [cheaper](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/)! You can store 5TB of data for less than $150, and if you add geo redundancy it will costs you like $250 per month. And database size in Azure SQL is not unlimited. With this amount of data you may not be able to use it anyway (or the price will be mind blowing).

My recommendation is if you need to store them in the cloud to go for Azure Storage Blobs.